# Can I get a device connected to my access point to communicate with a device connected directly to my router?

Tags: home-networking

We have a fairly unique network setup. Basically we have a modem/router downstairs and a wireless router upstairs connected to the modem/router downstairs by Ethernet used as an access point.

The only device connected to the downstairs modem/router is our LG WebOS TV by Ethernet. Everything else is connected to the upstairs wireless router.

I’d like to setup the AnyMote app with my TV so I can control it by the app, is this possible? If so how? At the moment it can’t see it.

DOWNSTAIRS MODEM/ROUTER – LG WEBOS TV DOWNSTAIRS MODEM/ROUTER – UPSTAIRS WIRELESS ROUTER – ALL OTHER DEVICES

Hope that makes sense, thanks. The app allows you to enter IP addresses and ports manually if needed.

Comment: Do you have the Access point connected to the WAN port or a LAN port?  Is DHCP turned off on it?

Comment: In other words, the first one does NAT & DHCP, the 2nd one just needs to be in Bridge mode; then everything is on the same network

Answer (score 0):

If your access point is simply that it should be bridging the network so to speak. That is, devices connected to the upstairs AP (access point) should have the same IP addressing scheme as devices connected to the router downstairs and speak on the same subnet. If this is the case then all "hosts" connected to these "nodes" should be able to speak to one another.

You could test this if you had a device connected to the router downstairs, retrieve its local IP address, then used a device upstairs connected to the AP to "ping" the IP you copied from the downstairs, router connected device. A little convoluted but a good test none the less.

If you continue having trouble from there I would look into what modes you have for the access point (usually an access point or wireless bridge mode will get you where you need to be) and double check that it is indeed using the same network as the main router. Ideally, the main router downstairs should be the only one deciding IP addresses and NAT, while the Access point should literally be just that, an addition point of access to the downstairs router.